# R case insensitive if check

Tags: r, if-statement, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

What is the best way to create a case insensitive if statement?

For example if I have `var = 'ignore'`

```
if(var == 'Ignore'){print("pass")} else{print("fail")}
```

Will fail.

Some options that will pass include:

```
if(var == 'Ignore' | var == 'ignore' ){print("pass")} else{print("fail")}

if(tolower(var) == tolower('Ignore') ){print("pass")} else{print("fail")}

if(toupper(var) == toupper('Ignore') ){print("pass")} else{print("fail")}
```

Are there any other good options? Is there a best option(s)?

I'm not sure how "best" should be measured

Comment: I read your comment that you searched SO before. Duly noted. I had to edit it out (due to the way and where in your question it was written) but I figured I'd leave this comment to acknowledge it. I don't understand what you meant with your use of `[1]` in the question body tho. That seems random. You want that edited out, right? I'm just going to edit it.

Comment: @Hack-R Thank you for the edits. The [1] was supposed to be a footnote - is there a better way of doing that? Do you have any advice on how better to indicate the mentioned SO search in a question? Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I see. That's actually the same markdown used for hyperlinks (not the markdown used to create them, but the markdown generated automatically by the editor when you create them), so basically anything other than that would work. Personally, if I have to do it, I use a triple asterisk.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `grepl` with `ignore.case = T`

```
var <- "ignore"
if (grepl("Ignore", var, ignore.case = T)) "Pass" else "Fail"
#[1] "Pass"
```

Or using `stringr::str_detect` with `fixed(pattern, ignore_case = T)`

```
library(stringr)
if (str_detect(var, fixed("Ignore", ignore_case = T))) "Pass" else "Fail"
#[1] "Pass"
```

Comment: Those are helpful thank you! Do you have any recommendation on a "best" method? Maybe for example if this was going to be repeated across a large set of test cases.

Comment: thank you, but this might fail if var has something like "mignore" or "ignored" as it contains ignore. but we want to match only "ignore". please suggest.